# System.AccessViolationException - C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача: сделать так, чтобы события **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ** начали прогружаться в тот момент, как произошло событие нажатия кнопки клавиатуры на **ПЕРВОЙ ФОРМЕ** (которая и запускает **ВТОРУЮ ФОРМУ**) - то есть асинхронно.

Зачем это вообще нужно:

Представим себе форму оформления закладок (**ПЕРВАЯ ФОРМА**). При нажатии на клавишу "Добавить закладку" происходит запуск и открытие **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ** - формы оформления закладок. В ней расположены 2 текстовых окна, в которых пользователь может писать текст.

Так вот, допустим, человек, пользующийся приложением, достаточно не умён (ну или же представим себе очень дотошного тестировщика), и он, при нажатии на кнопку добавления закладки **НА ПЕРВОЙ ФОРМЕ**, не дожидаясь прогрузки **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ**, начинает судорожно стучать по клавишам клавиатуры (или же в ту же секунду, как **ВТОРАЯ ФОРМА** отображается, начинает заполнять её, не дожидаясь 0,5 с на прогрузку всех инструкций и событий **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ**), и, о ужас, приложение крашится (ну а если действие происходит в самое IDE VS, то вылезает странная ошибка - "System.Access.ViolationException").

Как я понял, эта ошибка / краш возникает вследствие того, что программа не успевает обработать инструкцию - событие изменения текста - **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ** ,- а события с ней уже происходят (пользователь вводит текст).

Как можно ускорить загрузку событий **ВТОРОЙ ФОРМЫ** (мой вариант -  обрабатывать их асинхронно) или хотя бы вылечить появление данной ошибки?

**Ошибка перехвату "catch" не поддаётся - как сказано на сайте Microsoft, на StackOverFlow и как выяснено на практике.**

Примеры вместе с кодом прикрепляю ниже.

*И да, для особо умных, я посмотрел все возможные варианты поиска - решение моей проблемы не нашёл, так что не следует совать мне первые ссылки со StackOverFlow и т.п., как будто я их не видел.*

Код главной формы:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    readonly DataManipulatorClass CurrentData = null; // переменная хранимых данных проекта
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
        
        CurrentData = DataManipulatorClass.LoadData(); // загрузка данных проекта в переменную
        
        LoadSavedData(); // осуществление загрузки данных
    }
    
    // Инициализация экземпляров форм //
    private BookmarkEditor BookmarkEditorForm; // инициализация экземпляра формы оформления закладок
    private BookmarkContentEditor BookmarkContentEditorForm; // инициализация экземпляра формы оформления содержимого закладки
    private Form WebBrowserForm; // инициализация экземпляра формы веб-браузера
    private WebBrowser LinkWebBrowser; // инициализация экземпляра веб-браузера
    
    // События //
    
    // Событие создания новой закладки
    private void AddBookmarkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateBookmark();
        
        using (BookmarkEditorForm = new BookmarkEditor() // создание экземпляра формы оформления закладок
        // >> (можно и без using, но в данном случае это мало что изменит)
        {
            _ContentsBookmarkList = this.ContentsBookmarkList, // передача ссылки на дерево закладок созданной форме
            _BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox = this.BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox, // передача ссылки на текстовое поле описания закладки созданной форме
            _BookmarkTimeInfoTextBox = this.BookmarkTimeInfoTextBox, // передача ссылки на текстовое поле времени создания / редактирования закладки созданной форме
            _BookmarkChapterInfoTextBox = this.BookmarkChapterInfoTextBox, // передача ссылки на текстовое поле главы закладки созданной форме
            _BookmarkContentRichTextBox = this.BookmarkContentRichTextBox // передача ссылки на текстовое поле содержимого закладки созданной форме
        })
        
        {
            BookmarkEditorForm.ShowDialog(); // открытие формы оформления закладок
        }
    }
    
    // Метод создания новой закладки >> (особой роли не играет в данном случае)
    private void CreateBookmark()
    {
        TreeNode NewBookmark;
        
        if (ContentsBookmarkList.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            NewBookmark = ContentsBookmarkList.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add("Новая закладка");
        }
        
        else
        {
            NewBookmark = ContentsBookmarkList.Nodes.Add("Новая закладка");
        }
        
        ContentsBookmarkList.SelectedNode = NewBookmark;
    }
}
```

Код второй, вызываемой формы:

```
public partial class BookmarkEditor : Form
{
    public BookmarkEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.AllowDrop = true;
        
        // Подписки на события перетаскивания текста в описание закладки
        BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox_DragEnter);
        BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox_DragDrop);
    }

    // Получение ссылок //
    public TreeView _ContentsBookmarkList; // получение ссылки на дерево закладок
    public RichTextBox _BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox; // получение ссылки на текстовое поле главной формы описания закладки
    public TextBox _BookmarkTimeInfoTextBox; // получение ссылки на текстовое поле главной формы данных о создании / редактировании закладки
    public TextBox _BookmarkChapterInfoTextBox; // получение ссылки на текстовое поле главной формы данных о главе закладки
    public RichTextBox _BookmarkContentRichTextBox; // получение ссылки на текстовое поле главной формы содержания закладки

    // Создание событий //
    private event EventHandler AbortButton_Clicked; // создание события проверки нажатия кнопки отмены
    private event EventHandler ConfirmButton_Clicked; // создание события проверки нажатия кнопки подтверждения

    // События //
    
    // Событие нажатия кнопки отмены добавления закладки
    private void AddBookmarkAbortButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbortButton_Clicked += AddBookmarkAbortButton_Click;
        
        _ContentsBookmarkList.SelectedNode.Remove();
        _ContentsBookmarkList.SelectedNode = null; // снятие выделения с добавленной закладки
        
        this.Close();
        this.Dispose(true);
    }
    
    string BookmarkName; // название закладки

    // Событие изменения текста названия закладки >> ИМЕННО ИЗ-ЗА НЕГО И ВОЗНИКАЕТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
    private void BookmarkNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BookmarkName = BookmarkNameTextBox.Text;
    }
    
    // Событие изменения текста описания закладки >> ИМЕННО ИЗ-ЗА НЕГО И ВОЗНИКАЕТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
    private void BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.Lines.Length > 10 || BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.TextLength > 770 || (BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.Lines.Length >= 0 && BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.TextLength > 55))
        {
            BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
        }
        
        else
        {
            BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        }
    }
    
    // Событие проверки данных перед закрытием формы
    private void BookmarkEditor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (AbortButton_Clicked != null)
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
        }
        
        else if (BookmarkName == null || BookmarkName == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Вы не ввели название закладки! Пожалуйста, введите название закладки");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        
        else if (ConfirmButton_Clicked == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Вы не подтвердили название закладки! Пожалуйста, подтвердите название закладки");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        
        AbortButton_Clicked -= AddBookmarkAbortButton_Click;
        ConfirmButton_Clicked -= AddBookmarkConfirmButton_Click;
    }
}
```

Стек вызовов:

```
    [Внешний код]   
>   Digital schoolbook.exe!Digital_schoolbook.MainWindow.AddBookmarkButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Строка 55   C#
    [Внешний код]   
    Digital schoolbook.exe!Digital_schoolbook.Program.Main() Строка 19  C#
```

Сведения ошибки:

```
-       $exception  {"Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."}   System.AccessViolationException
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2147467261 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        Message "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена." string
        Source  "System.Windows.Forms"  string
        StackTrace  "   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()\r\n   at Digital_schoolbook.MainWindow.AddBookmarkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\\Users\\evtyk\\source\\repos\\Digital schoolbook\\Digital schoolbook\\Project.cs:line 55\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)\r\n   at Digital_schoolbook.Program.Main() in C:\\Users\\evtyk\\source\\repos\\Digital schoolbook\\Digital schoolbook\\Program.cs:line 19"  string
-       TargetSite  {IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr, IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)}  System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
        Attributes  Public | Static | HideBySig | PinvokeImpl   System.Reflection.MethodAttributes
        CallingConvention   Standard    System.Reflection.CallingConventions
        ContainsGenericParameters   false   bool
        CustomAttributes    Метод System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData>
+       DeclaringType   GenericParameterAttributes = {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}, GenericTypeArguments = Метод System.Type.get_GenericTypeArguments невозможно вызвать в этом контексте. System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
        IsAbstract  false   bool
        IsAssembly  false   bool
        IsConstructor   false   bool
        IsFamily    false   bool
        IsFamilyAndAssembly false   bool
        IsFamilyOrAssembly  false   bool
        IsFinal false   bool
        IsGenericMethod false   bool
        IsGenericMethodDefinition   false   bool
        IsHideBySig true    bool
        IsPrivate   false   bool
        IsPublic    true    bool
        IsSecurityCritical  Метод System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityCritical невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.   bool
        IsSecuritySafeCritical  Метод System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecuritySafeCritical невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.   bool
        IsSecurityTransparent   Метод System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsSecurityTransparent невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.    bool
        IsSpecialName   false   bool
        IsStatic    true    bool
        IsVirtual   false   bool
        MemberType  Method  System.Reflection.MemberTypes
        MetadataToken   100664855   int
+       MethodHandle    {System.RuntimeMethodHandle}    System.RuntimeMethodHandle
        MethodImplementationFlags   Метод System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_MethodImplementationFlags невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.   System.Reflection.MethodImplAttributes
+       Module  {System.Windows.Forms.dll}  System.Reflection.Module {System.Reflection.RuntimeModule}
        Name    "CallWindowProc"    string
+       ReflectedType   "((System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo)($exception).TargetSite).ReflectedType" выдал исключение типа "System.NotSupportedException" System.Type {System.NotSupportedException}
+       ReturnParameter {System.IntPtr }    System.Reflection.ParameterInfo
+       ReturnType  GenericParameterAttributes = {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}, GenericTypeArguments = Метод System.Type.get_GenericTypeArguments невозможно вызвать в этом контексте. System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
        ReturnTypeCustomAttributes  Метод System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_ReturnTypeCustomAttributes невозможно вызвать в этом контексте.   System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider
+       Члены, не являющиеся открытыми      
+       Статические члены       
+       Члены, не являющиеся открытыми
```

Подробности ошибки:

```
System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Сообщение = Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.
  Источник = <Не удается определить источник исключения>
  Трассировка стека:
<Не удается определить трассировку стека исключения>
```

Окно вывода:

```
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Users\evtyk\source\repos\Digital schoolbook\Digital schoolbook\bin\Debug\Digital schoolbook.exe". Символы загружены.
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll". Сборка модуля выполнена без символов.
Вызвано исключение: "System.AccessViolationException" в System.Windows.Forms.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.AccessViolationException" в System.Windows.Forms.dll
Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

"Digital schoolbook.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: Digital schoolbook.exe). Загружено "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Desktop.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
```

[image: Форма 1 (главная форма)]

[image: Форма 2 (форма оформления закладок)]

[image: Возникающая ошибка, которая не перехватывается]

[image: Сведения исключения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141585/discussion-on-question-by-chaos-sower-system-accessviolationexception-c-winf).

Answer (score -1):

Как вы справедливо отметили, действительно, ошибка возникает вследствие быстрого ввода текста во вторую форму - программа не успевает выполнить инструкцию проверки условия, - из-за этого и возникает ваша ошибка (в этом легко убедиться, подставив следующую строку в конструкции события перед проверкой условия: `Thread.Sleep(12);`). Но вам не нужно для этого вызывать вторую форму, как вы выразились, асинхронно.

Поскольку ваше приложение довольно простое, не использующее другие потоки, то можно асинхронно вызывать событие изменения текста в полях TextBox второй формы. Для этого поменяйте строки кода второй формы на следующие:

```
// Событие изменения текста названия закладки
private async void BookmarkNameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        BookmarkNameTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            BookmarkName = BookmarkNameTextBox.Text;
        });
    });
}

// Событие изменения текста описания закладки
private async void BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.Lines.Length > 10 || BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.TextLength > 770 || (BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.Lines.Length >= 0 && BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.TextLength > 55))
            {
                BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
            }
            
            else
            {
                BookmarkDescriptionRichTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Сразу прошу заметить, что я НЕ ЭКСПЕРТ в области потоков данных (как, я могу заметить, и вы)**, тем не менее, применив данное решение на деле, **ошибка более не возникала**.

**Оффтоп. А всем тем "гениальным экспертам" я могу лишь посоветовать либо вникнуть в вопрос и помочь человеку (запрашивая необходимую информацию, если её не хватает), либо вообще не лезть в вопрос, на который вы не можете дать ответ, а не топить вопрос человека, как и его ответ.*

Если кто-нибудь найдёт более подходящее решение проблемы - прошу быть смелым в его публикации. Если где-то необходимо поправить мой ответ, - пожалуйста, поправьте меня, а не пишите: "Так делать нельзя! Как вам вообще такая идея в голову пришла?! То что вы предлагаете - неправильно и глупо" (так если это так - выложите свой, "правильный ответ", а не пустословьте).

Comment: Хех, рубрика "помоги себе сам" XD

Comment: Кстати, лайфхак на будущее: если у вас падает подозрение на какую-то строчку кода, то поставьте перед ней ```Thread.Sleep(12);```, так у вас, если данная строчка действительно вызывает ошибку, будет происходит исключение при каждом случае (так я смог выяснить проблему со своим кодом)

Comment: Нет, так делать нельзя. Нельзя работать с разделяемыми объектами, кроме контролов UI, из другого потока.